# Accessing a frame in a video

Tags: android, video

I am using `getFrameAtTime()` method of `MediaMetadataRetriever` class to get a frame located at a particular time in a video(mp4). This works fine when the video is of low resolution say 480 x 270. But if I use HD version (1280 x 720) of same video then it force closes. Is there any way out ?

Comment: Do you get any error or anything, we need more info to help you out.

Comment: @Ruuhkis I have logcat details

Comment: what is on this line AsinActivity.java:37

Comment: @Ruuhkis on line 37 I have        g=bmp.getWidth();     but why do u ask for line 37 ? bmp is the bitmap received from the getFrameAtTime()

Comment: that basically means that the bmp it receives is null, according to the error. We need the whole code to help you out if you can't figure out why it returns null.. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with codes. I was using videos dowloaded from youtube. If videos are shot using android, it will work.